# Inequality with differences in sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $a_1,\ldots,a_n, b_1,\ldots,b_n$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $0 \le a_1+\dots+a_n\le 1$ and $0 \le b_1+\dots+b_n\le 1$. Let $c_i = a_i-b_i$ for each $i$. Prove or disprove that
> $$4n\cdot\max(|c_1|,\dots,|c_n|) + 2n \ge 2 + (n+1)(|c_1|+\dots+|c_n|+|c_1+\dots+c_n|).$$

The inequality can be equality when $a_i = 1/n$ and $b_i = 0$ for all $i$ -- the left-hand side is $4+2n$ and the right-hand side is $2 + (n+1)\cdot 2 = 2n+4$. In order to prove the inequality, an attempt is to use $$|c_1+\dots+c_n| \le |c_1|+\dots+|c_n| \le n\cdot\max(|c_1|,\dots,|c_n|)$$
to write everything in terms of $|c_1|+\dots+|c_n|$.
This reduces the inequality to $|c_1|+\dots+|c_n| \le 1$, but it is not always true.